# Open specific file with extension (.htm) in MS Access with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, environ

I am trying to open a file in Access. I am in the correct folder location but I am unaware of the file name. In this case I would like to open the file with the extension of .htm. I have seen an example of excel but this doesn't seem to work for me:

```
FolderPath = GetSignature(Environ("Userprofile") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\")

FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.htm")

While FileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open FolderPath & FileName
    FileName = Dir()
Wend
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What debugging have you done, what is the return of folderpath, filename etc what is the error if you get one?  It works for me, what is GetSignature

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Are you trying to open the file as an Excel "workbook"?  Do you have an Excel `Application` object defined?